# Automate SNAPSHOT isolation level for a particular SQL user

Tags: sql-server

I need to have some users that are systematiically in the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT when they logs to the database.

I tried to use a LOGON trigger to set the user session to that isolation level when the ORIGINAL_LOGIN() was the user I wanted to promote... But this does not works...

I tried to see if it was possible to configure this in the ODBC connection strings.... but I found nothing

This is my actual code to test...

**First part** the source database :

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_SOURCE;
GO

ALTER DATABASE DB_SOURCE
   SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
GO

USE DB_SOURCE;
GO

CREATE TABLE T (C INT);
GO

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1), (2), (3);
GO`enter code here`
```

**Second part**, the login and the user :

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN CNX_USER_TEST 
   WITH PASSWORD = 'foo', 
        DEFAULT_DATABASE = DB_SOURCE;
GO

USE DB_SOURCE;
GO

CREATE USER USR_USER_TEST 
   FROM LOGIN CNX_USER_TEST;
GO

GRANT SELECT TO USR_USER_TEST;
GO
```

**Third part**, the logon trigger :

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER E_LOGON
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS N'sa' 
FOR LOGON
AS  
BEGIN  
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= N'CNX_USER_TEST'
BEGIN
   COMMIT;
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
END;
END;
```

**Fourth**, the test...

In SSMS window 1 :

```
BEGIN TRAN ;

UPDATE T SET C = C + 1;
```

In SSMS in another window connected with CNX_USER_TEST :

```
SELECT * FROM T;
```

Blocked !

Comment: Why don't you just set the database as a whole to use read committed snapshot isolation as default?

Comment: There's very little point to this even if you should somehow succeed. The client can always override the transaction isolation level after login. Many may have their libraries do so without them even knowing. If you want to enforce `SNAPSHOT` isolation, that's what the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` setting is for. This will still be thwarted by clients who deviate from the default `READ COMMITTED`, but that's rare.

Comment: Or use a Read-Scale AG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16, or a readable replica if you have an existing AG.

Comment: The customer does not have AG and does not want to. We need to stay in READ COMMITTED isolation level by default for the application. I know that after login we can set the ISOLATION LEVEL for the all session, but because this user is used for a reporting tool we do not have anyway to code the command to do so...

Comment: An option is to set `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` and have the application work on views only (you could do this by assigning a default schema for the user, and mirroring the tables as views) and using the `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` hint in these views where you do *not* want snapshot isolation. This is admittedly a little roundabout, but might be the only way if you can't change the application itself. (Note that there is no reverse option to force `SNAPSHOT` on an individual basis; that's valid only on memory-optimized tables).

Comment: Interresting.. I was trying to do the reverse... Create a new DB with view with a SNAPSHOT table tag, but this do not wroks because WITH(SNAPSHOT) is reserved to In Memory tables...

Comment: I think it will be interesting to ask MS to have such a hint for views to use SNAPSHOT isolation when ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION is ON on a DB... (Azure SQL feedback...)